# How can i check whether temporary queue is created or not in activemq?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

i am new to activemq.i created one temporary queue. i can get the temporary queue name from my application using below code.

```
  Destination temdest=session.createTemporaryQueue();   
 System.out.println("<<Temporary Queue Name while connection is active: >>"+temdest.toString());
```

when i create one static queue, i can see my queue name  under queue  in activemq.but when i create one temporary queue i can't see that.so how can i check whether temporary queue is created or not ?is there any way to see temporary queue in activemq ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not (yet) possible via the web console, but per [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) via JConsole (see screenshot below).
But you have to ensure that the broker provides JMX information on your specified port (default 1099), so check the server configuration first.

But remind, normally you don't need to check whether a temporary queue was created. To check that per JMX is like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

[image: JConsole TempQueue]

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the connection in the AMQ console on the 'Connections' tab you can click on it and it shows you the list of Destinations being listened to including temporary queues.